# Dependency Injection failure during mvn install loading standalone run

Tags: maven, junit, dependency-injection, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a RESTful service created using Spring MVC. I created an integration test to test my Rest controller, using spring-test mvcmock.

When I am running this test using run as Junit. It is running fine. 
However, when the same test is getting executed during `mvn install`, using surefire plugin. This test is complaining throwing fatal error:

> No qualifying bean of type ...

When I checked previous logs it says that it loaded 0 dependecy.
This was the log :

> DEBUG XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loaded 0 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath*:service-test-context.xml]

However, I again run this test class as Junit and I could see "loaded 23 beans at the same log line."

**Question**: Could you please suggest, what can be the issue?

Note: 
This is multi maven module application and dependency of another module is not getting injected. 
I was getting same issue, when I was running this test as Junit. Then I added dependent modules in eclipse > build > project and issue got resolved in run as JUnit. Now getting this issue while doing `mvn install`.

Comment: Does your JUnit runner class end in **Test** ? Also have you tried **mvn clean install**   ?

Comment: No, but it is getting called. Is it must to end its name with Test. You can include any expression in you surefire configuration. I tried mvn clean install as well, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your surefire configuration contain an **includes** parameter?

"A list of  elements specifying the tests (by pattern) that should be included in testing. When not specified and when the test parameter is not specified, the default includes will be

```
<includes>
 <include>**/Test*.java</include>
 <include>**/*Test.java</include>
 <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

"

Easy fix is to rename your test runner so that it ends in **Test.java**.  Then

```
mvn test
```

will pick it up.

**Updated**

An alternative is this:

"test:
Specify this parameter to run individual tests by file name, overriding the includes/excludes parameters. Each pattern you specify here will be used to create an include pattern formatted like **/${test}.java, so you can just type "-Dtest=MyTest" to run a single test called "foo/MyTest.java". The test patterns prefixed with a ! will be excluded.
This parameter overrides the includes/excludes parameters, and the TestNG suiteXmlFiles parameter. Since 2.7.3, you can execute a limited number of methods in the test by adding #myMethod or #my*ethod. For example, "-Dtest=MyTest#myMethod". This is supported for junit 4.x and testNg.

Since 2.19 a complex syntax is supported in one parameter (JUnit 4, JUnit 4.7+, TestNG):
"-Dtest=???Test, !Unstable*, pkg/**/Ci*leTest.java, *Test#test*One+testTwo?????, #fast*+slowTest"
"-Dtest=Basic*, !%regex[.*.Unstable.*], !%regex[.*.MyTest.class#one.*|two.*], %regex[#fast.*|slow.*]"

The Parameterized JUnit runner describes test methods using an index in brackets, so the non-regex method pattern would become: #testMethod[*]. If using @Parameters(name="{index}: fib({0})={1}") and selecting the index e.g. 5 in pattern, the non-regex method pattern would become #testMethod[5:*].

```
Type: java.lang.String
Required: No
User Property: test
```

"

So if your test runner was named **foo/MyVeryOwnRunner.java** you could do the following

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=MyVeryOwnRunner
```

Comment: I have a spare that ends in Test**s**.java and it doesn't run unless I rename it and drop the **s**.

Comment: Issue is not related to running the test case. It is getting run. However, required dependecies are not getting loaded.

Comment: Ah.  You have to add <scope>provided</scope> to your external jars.

Comment: The default scope is **compile**. **provided** means that you have it defined on the target system. Since this is a mock you probably need scope **test**.

Comment: Default is compile and as it is the superset of all, it should make dependency available during test execution as well.

Comment: But its not available during test.

Comment: I changed scope to provided, it didn't work. Then, I changed to everything else, still it didn't work. Any help?

Comment: OK. Hypothesis if it works in JUnit then the jar must be in the JUnitclasspath. If it fails in Maven then the jar is not in the Maven default classpath. JUnit relies on the CLASSPATH environment variable. List/echo CLASSPATH. Please confirm that folder containing jar is present.  Maven Surefire looks for jars in ${project.build.testOutputDirectory}, in ${project.build.outputDirectory}, in the project dependencies, and in <additionalClasspathElements> defined in pom.xml under Surefire <configuration>. There is a folder specified in env var CLASSPATH not in Maven's 4 places.

Comment: ${project.build.testOutputDirectory} is **src/test/java** unless overridden. ${project.build.outputDirectory} is **target/classes** unless overriden. Question: Have you defined your [repositories](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/trunk/maven-model-builder/src/main/resources/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml#L53) to Maven so that it can find your jars?

Comment: @PrashantBhardwaj Which command line path are you in (pwd) and what is the exact mvn command you execute?

Comment: I am just inside my repo directory, where I have all my maven modules infront of me and I am trying 'mvn clean install'

Comment: I took a look.  Seems like the top folder is not where you want to run tests.  What happens if you do a mvn clean install from folder scorer/ScoreBoard/scoreboard.validation